# Tkinter - Change Label Text/Entry on Button Click

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label, tkinter-entry

I have two labels and entry fields (**A & B**). When I enter the username/password for "*A Username/A Password*", I want to click the "Submit" button, then have the labels/entry fields change to "*B Username/B Password*" and be able to click the "Submit" button again, using `Tkinter`.

**Python Code**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a_user_var = tk.StringVar()
a_pass_var = tk.StringVar()

b_user_var = tk.StringVar()
b_pass_var = tk.StringVar()

def submit():

    a_user = a_user_var.get()
    a_pass = a_pass_var.get()

    a_user_var.set("")
    a_pass_var.set("")

    b_user = b_user_var.get()
    b_pass = b_pass_var.get()

    b_user_var.set("")
    b_pass_var.set("")

a_user_label = tk.Label(root, text="A Username")
a_user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=a_user_var)

a_pass_label = tk.Label(root, text="A Password")
a_pass_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=a_pass_var, show="•")

b_user_label = tk.Label(root, text="B Username")
b_user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=b_user_var)

b_pass_label = tk.Label(root, text="B Password")
b_pass_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=b_pass_var, show="•")

sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)

a_user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
a_user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

a_pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
a_pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

b_user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
b_user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

b_pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

sub_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**Current Result**

[image]

**Desired Result (after clicking Submit button)**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create a unique label and entry widgets for `A` and `B`.  Instead just use one set of widgets and change the label's text upon pressing the button to `B`.  If you need to store the contents of the entry widget, you can grab the label text and parse it to see which character the specific set belongs to.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
user_var = tk.StringVar()
pass_var = tk.StringVar()
entries = {}

def submit():
    user = user_var.get()
    passw = pass_var.get()
    label_text = user_label["text"]
    char = label_text.split()[0]
    entries[char] = (user, passw)
    if char == "A":
        user_label["text"] = "B" + label_text[1:]
        pass_label["text"] = "B" + pass_label["text"][1:]
    user_var.set('')
    pass_var.set('')
    print(entries)


user_label = tk.Label(root, text="A Username")
user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=user_var)

pass_label = tk.Label(root, text="A Password")
pass_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pass_var, show="•")

sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
sub_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)

user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This configuration still holds on to the user input from "A", instead of clearing it.

Comment: @arnpry you just need to clear the stringVar's I edited answer

Comment: Thank you @Alexander! One other question... I noticed that after "A" user/pass has been inputted, the list for "B" contains both "A" and "B" user/pass entries, instead of just "B" user/pass. Screenshot --> https://i.imgur.com/B8zsg7g.png

Comment: @arnpry  it isn't a list.  it is a dictionary and it is a global variable `entries`. I did that because I assume that you plan on using the information input from the `A` user,  and the `B` user after both have entered their information.  If that isn't the case then you can just move the `entries` variable inside of the `submit` function and it will no longer be the case